# Probability in the game Resistance

Tags: probability

I was playing the game Resistance with a group of 10 people. In the game, people are given one of two "assignments". 6 people are given cards that tell them they are part of the Resistance. 4 people are spies trying to sabotage missions.

When we first apportion the roles to people, we hand out the stack of roles, and each person takes one, and then passes the stack to the person to their right around the circle clockwise.

One person (the director for the purposes of clarification) is then chosen "at random", to create a subgroup of 3 people that they hope to contain no spies. This is frequently done with locally, i.e. The director chooses 3 people themself, and the two people immediately next to them.

I want to know if this group of 3 people is more, less, or equally likely to contain a spy than if the director chose the people in a more "true random fashion"?

If you were to do it with marbles, you would put 6 Red marbles, and 4 Blue marbles into a bag. Then you would take them out one at a time, at random, and put them into a row without looking at them. I'm asking, if you're more or less likely to pick 3 red marbles if you just pick 3 of them in a row vs. choosing by rolling a die, or something.

Comment: What's not truly random about this fashion?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. I would accept that choosing based on locality is the same as true random, but I would like an explanation as to why that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're referring to the possibility that the director might be able to tell from people's expressions which card they got, we can obviously not predict mathematically whether this increases or decreases the chances of picking a spy.

Assuming that the director can gain no information about the cards, the process is uniformly random; just imagine the cards being dealt after the selection process.

*Edit*: I just saw your edit; apparently it's the second alternative. This sort of problem is resolved by noting the irrelevance of the temporal order. Another way to think about it is to note that the symmetry between the outcomes can't be broken by a process that respects the symmetry.